# copy selected columns in a row to another sheet if a cell meets a condition

Tags: excel, vba

(not in a range, not adjacent columns)

(in given order)

I have many rows on Sheet1. I would like to copy some columns of a row (not the entire row and not a range of columns) to Sheet2 (to the first empty row of Sheet2) if a cell satisfies a condition (the cell in the current row and A column has a value of y)
I would like to copy not the entire row from Sheet1 only the row with those columns that are given on Sheet3 (Column A), and the new column number (on Sheet2) is also given on Sheet3 (column B)

It would be simple if my task would be to copy the entire row, or the selected column would be in a range...but i would need to copy those columns that are specialized on Sheet3. I would be grateful for any help. Thanks in advance.

Sheet1 shows an example data sheet. The criteria is if Cells(Rows, 1).Value = "y"
Sheet2 shows the desired result.
Sheet3 shows the selected column number on Sheet1 and the new column number on Sheet2

[image: Sheet1]

[image: Sheet2]

[image: Sheet3]

Answer (score 1):

Whilst this probably should be done using arrays more, here's some basic VBA code that loops the first sheet checking for "y" in the first column. When it finds it, it then loops the column mappings in the third sheet that have been saved into arrays to set the values on the second sheet:

```
Sub sTranasferData()
    On Error GoTo E_Handle
    Dim aOld() As Variant
    Dim aNew() As Variant
    Dim wsIn As Worksheet
    Dim wsOut As Worksheet
    Dim wsTrack As Worksheet
    Dim lngLastRow As Long
    Dim lngLoop1 As Long
    Dim lngLoop2 As Long
    Dim lngRow As Long
    Dim lngTrack As Long
    Set wsIn = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set wsOut = Worksheets("Sheet2")
    Set wsTrack = Worksheets("Sheet3")
    lngLastRow = wsIn.Cells(wsIn.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    lngTrack = wsTrack.Cells(wsTrack.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    aOld() = wsTrack.Range("A2:A" & lngTrack).Value
    aNew() = wsTrack.Range("B2:B" & lngTrack).Value
    lngRow = 1
    For lngLoop1 = 2 To lngLastRow
        If wsIn.Cells(lngLoop1, 1) = "y" Then
            For lngLoop2 = LBound(aOld) To UBound(aOld)
                wsOut.Cells(lngRow, aNew(lngLoop2, 1)) = wsIn.Cells(lngLoop1, aOld(lngLoop2, 1))
            Next lngLoop2
            lngRow = lngRow + 1
        End If
    Next lngLoop1
sExit:
    On Error Resume Next
    Set wsIn = Nothing
    Set wsOut = Nothing
    Set wsTrack = Nothing
    Exit Sub
E_Handle:
    MsgBox Err.Description & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "sTransferData", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Error: " & Err.Number
    Resume sExit
End Sub
```

Regards,

Comment: Thank you so much, it works well. Array was a good idea, thanks.